# Python DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found on microsoft fastRCNN script

Tags: python, dll, importerror, cntk

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my python script:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A1_GenerateInputROIs.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PARAMETERS
  File "C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta9-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN\PARAMETERS.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cntk_helpers import *
  File "C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta9-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN\cntk_helpers.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fastRCNN.nms import nms as nmsPython
  File "C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta9-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN\fastRCNN\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .imdb import imdb
  File "C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta9-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN\fastRCNN\imdb.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .utils3_win64.cython_bbox import bbox_overlaps
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

I'm following the tutorial at https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN. I also got stuck with a similar error when I tried to run the script on a ubuntu system.

Where do you think the problem comes from?

One hypothesis I'm exploring is the following:

Because on the tutorial, it says:

> This tutorial code assumes you are using 64bit version of Python 3.4,
>   as the Fast R-CNN DLL files under utils_win64 are prebuilt for this
>   version

and since I'm using python 3.5 and not python 3.4, I'm starting to think that maybe it is the cause. I will keep you informed of my findings.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could create a 3.4 env within the 3.5 python distribution as shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/622461/how-do-i-create-a-python-3-3-environment-with-anaconda-windows). Then report if you are seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you, it now works! Python 3.5 instead of Python 3.4 was indeed the problem.